# Problem in Ubuntu Installation

Tags: system-installation, 32-bit, system

Recently I decided to start using Ubuntu. I have a Lenovo S10-3t laptop.
It has no CD drive, so I tried to install Ubuntu via Universal USB installer.
The problem I am facing is, that I do the process like

1. Choose the OS I want to Install
2. Select the ISO file I have downloaded
3. Choose the (c:) partition and format my hard drive in FAT32.

In the end I press "Create" and immediately after that this message pops up

```
ABORTING! (c:) contains a WINDOWS/SYSTEM 32 directory.
```

So eventually I can't go on to the format and install.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is at 3)
you have to format your USB drive not your C partition.. this creates a Live image. reboot then with the USB plugged and proceed with the installation

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply Alex! Another question, Why should I format the hard drive in which I won't put the OS?What I wnat is to replace Windows with UBUNDU in the c: and also not loose all my files in the external hard drive. Again thank you very much!! :)

Comment: for your files, you need to do a backup or you'll loose all your data (photo, music, docs)

the .iso file you've downloaded it's just an installation file and you have to burn it on something like, in your case, a flash drive..after that you can proceed with the real installation

Answer (score 0):

Your step **3.** is wrong. for Ubuntu installation your Pendrive should be bootable. after that you can install Ubuntu (or use as live cd).

In order to make your pendrive bootable **Choose you Pendrive** in 3rd step and completion of this process will make your Pendrive bootable.

after that when you try to install Ubuntu it will ask about type of installation then Choose **Replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu**.